# How to fix broken BIOS?

Tags: boot, bios, hardware-failure

Recently I bought an ASUS X542UQ laptop. Yesterday I got the option of update and shutdown, I thought it would be another Windows update so I clicked on it.
Now when it rebooted it asked me my BIOS password and then it took me to BIOS screen which read something like flash, I do not exactly remember what it was.

It then told me that setup paused, connect the power adapter to continue, which I did, but then it froze, so I turned it off by long pressing the power button.

Now when I again booted it up it did not asked me my BIOS password, instead there was nothing on the screen not even the ASUS logo, the power light was however on and the HDD and the fans were on.

I've tried many things to fix this, I even dismantled it to look for the CMOS battery; Which is not there.

ASUS support is not replying to my emails, and I do not have any service center in my city.

Comment: You probably broke it permanently. For future reference, once it starts a BIOS update, under no circumstances do you get in its way. It didn't freeze, it was doing the update in the background, they don't always give you a progress bar. Hopefully ASUS will accept a warranty claim.

Comment: What?? Is there no way to reflash the BIOS??

Comment: Some high end desktop motherboards have two BIOS chips for this exact problem, but I've never heard of a laptop having it. This is why it told you to plug in power while flashing BIOS. A sudden loss of power, like from holding the power button or a battery dying, can corrupt the BIOS.

Comment: "ASUS support is not replying to my emails," - You have had this problem less then a day.  You need to give ASUS more time to solve the problem.  ASUS does nt provide 24/7 technical support.